# Use % checking for particular server's path and compare with threshold value if it is greater than store in the file

Tags: ssh, disk-usage

Having a file `fi.csv` which has `name`, `path` and `superuser` by which we can login to servers. Using a script to check percent of disk usage. --- and compare it to a given treshold should store the data in `main.csv` file.

**Example `fi.csv`**

```
awlp212,/op/s,quick
awlp213,/AM/D,quick
```

**Output:**

```
Consumption is crossing threshold on /op/s on awlp212.
Consumption is 10 % on awlp13.
```

The script is giving correct result but do not store the result in  `main.csv`.

```bsh
for csv in $(cat fi.csv)
do
    a_server=`echo $csv | cut -d ',' -f 1`
    a_path=`echo $csv | cut -d ',' -f 2`
    user_id=`echo $csv | cut -d ',' -f 3`
    HOSTNAME=`hostname -A`
    ssh -n $user_id@$a_server path=$a_path ' 
    var=$(df -h|grep "$path$"|awk '\''{print $5}'\''|cut -d "%" -f1)
    host=$(hostname)

    if [[ $var -ge 60 ]]; then
        echo "Consumption is crossing threshold on $path on $host." 
    else
        echo "Consumption is $var % on $host. "
    fi' > main.csv
done
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Not sure what second sentence should say. You mean it should only write to `main.csv` if it's above threshold? (Title could indicate this), - but it conflicts with *script is giving correct result*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* storing the output in `main.csv`, but you're overwriting the file in each iteration of your loop.  Move the redirection to directly after `done` instead.

You are also trying to to do far too many things on the remote systems.  The only thing you need the remote system for is to run `du`, nothing else.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=, read -r remote pathname user
do
    ssh -n -l "$user" "$remote" "df -h '$pathname'" |
    awk -v h="$remote" -v p="$pathname" '
        NR == 2 {
            if (($5 + 0) > 60)
                level="WARNING"
            else
                level="INFO"
        
            printf "%s: %s disk usage for %s on %s\n", level, $5, p, h
        }'
done <fi.csv >output.txt
```

Here we simply read the comma-delimited input from `fi.csv`, call `du -h` for the path we're interested in, then we parse the result of that locally with `awk`.  The output is written to `output.txt`.

We know we're getting two lines back from `df`, so we make the `awk` code only care about the second line (`NR == 2`).  We then output a message showing the current disk usage percentage, prefixed by either `WARNING` or `INFO` depending on whether the percentage is over 60 or not.

Comment: It's working now thanks